# node_modules select2 replace wrappedMatcher with startMatcher

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I'm trying to change the select2.julll.js file from node_modules Angular 6 project.
So far I found some ways to do that tho, nothing has worked for me, would you fave any suggestions of how I can replace wrappedMatcher with startMatcher in select2 file?

```js
S2.define('select2/compat/matcher',[
  'jquery'
], function ($) {
  function oldMatcher (matcher) {
    function wrappedMatcher (params, data) {
      var match = $.extend(true, {}, data);

      if (params.term == null || $.trim(params.term) === '') {
        return match;
      }

      if (data.children) {
        for (var c = data.children.length - 1; c >= 0; c--) {
          var child = data.children[c];

          // Check if the child object matches
          // The old matcher returned a boolean true or false
          var doesMatch = matcher(params.term, child.text, child);

          // If the child didn't match, pop it off
          if (!doesMatch) {
            match.children.splice(c, 1);
          }
        }

        if (match.children.length > 0) {
          return match;
        }
      }

      if (matcher(params.term, data.text, data)) {
        return match;
      }

      return null;
    }

    return wrappedMatcher;
  }

  return oldMatcher;
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding the following code to my select2.directives.ts has solved my problem

```js
      if (data.text.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(params.term) > -1 &&
        !!data.text.toString().toLowerCase().startsWith(params.term.toString().toLowerCase())) {
        var modifiedData = $.extend({}, data, true);
        // modifiedData.text += ' (matched)';
        // You can return modified objects from here
        // This includes matching the `children` how you want in nested data sets
        return modifiedData;
      }
```